# error message when closing current position in binance futures, using ccxt library

Tags: python, api, trading, binance, ccxt

I am trading BTC/USDT through binance api with ccxt library.

The error happens when I am trying to close my current position in futures account.

I fetch exact amount of BTC i'm trading from my position.(ex. 0.011BTC)
and when i try to make an order to sell that amount of BTC to close my position,
error message comes out saying
Margin is insufficient.
which means i am trying to sell more BTC than i have in my position.

BUT the amount of BTC i am trying to sell is just fetched 0.1 seconds ago, and it is not changing.
so i have no idea what is going wrong.

and the problem is
this error DO NOT come out everytime.
same code sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't work.

I hope anyone have some idea how to fix this situation.

below is my code.

```
exchange = ccxt.binance({
    'apiKey': my_api_key,
    'secret': my_secret_key,
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    'options':{
        'defaultType':'future',
        'adjustForTimeDifference': True
    }})

positions = exchange.fapiPrivateGetPositionRisk()

for position in positions:

    # Check if position size is not zero
    if float(position['positionAmt']) != 0:
        # Determine the side of the order based on the position direction
        if float(position['positionAmt']) > 0:
            side = 'SELL'
        else:
            side = 'BUY'
        
        # Create a market order to close the position
        order = exchange.create_order(
            symbol=position['symbol'],
            type='MARKET',
            side=side,
            amount =abs(float(position['positionAmt'])),
            params={'reduceOnly': True}
            )
```

I get this error message

```
binance {"code":-2019,"msg":"Margin is insufficient."}
```

I have tried to fetch my position's BTC amount from other ccxt functions.

new code is below

```
balance = exchange.fetch_balance()
positions = balance['info']['positions']
for position in positions:
    if position['symbol'] == "BTCUSDT":
        amount = position['initialMargin']
```

above code also returns same error message,

```
binance {"code":-2019,"msg":"Margin is insufficient."}
```

still having problem to close my position.

help please.